# How can I implement Pencil Shades like hb, 2b, 4b, etc. to draw anything in Canvas of my Android Application?

Tags: android, android-canvas

I need to implement the pencil shades from 9b to 9h with the list showing the shades on pencil button Click() and after clicking the list item, the pencil should change to its new shade. Also need the eraser implementation on erase button click to erase the path drawn by pencil.

This is the code for drawing with a fixed size pen on a canvas without a button click. And the clearCanvas() method is called on button click that clears the whole Canvas.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private CanvasView customCanvas;
    private Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        customCanvas = (CanvasView) findViewById(R.id.custom_canvas);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.actionBar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        assert getSupportActionBar()!=null;
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    public void onClick(View view){
            customCanvas.clearCanvas();
    }
}



public class CanvasView extends View{
    public int width;
    public int height;
    private Bitmap mBitmap;
    private Canvas mCanvas;
    private Path mPath;
    Context context;
    private Paint mPaint, mErase;
    private float mX, mY;
    private static final float TOLERANCE = 5;
    private boolean erase=false;

    public CanvasView(Context c, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(c, attrs);
        // we set a new Path
        mPath = new Path();

        // and we set a new Paint with the desired attributes
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(4f);


    }

    // override onSizeChanged
    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

        // your Canvas will draw onto the defined Bitmap
        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
    }

    // override onDraw
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        // draw the mPath with the mPaint on the canvas when onDraw
        canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
    }


    // when ACTION_DOWN start touch according to the x,y values
    private void startTouch(float x, float y) {
        mPath.moveTo(x, y);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
    }

    // when ACTION_MOVE move touch according to the x,y values
    private void moveTouch(float x, float y) {
        float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
        float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
        if (dx >= TOLERANCE || dy >= TOLERANCE) {
            mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }
    }

    // Clear Canvas
    public void clearCanvas(){
        mPath.reset();
        invalidate();
    }

    // when ACTION_UP stop touch
    private void upTouch() {
        mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
    }

    //override the onTouchEvent
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                startTouch(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                moveTouch(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                upTouch();
                invalidate();
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

XML file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/actionBar"
            layout="@layout/action_bar" />

        <View
            android:layout_below="@+id/actionBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#2084AF" />

        <com.admin.mainactivity.CanvasView
            android:layout_below="@+id/actionBar"
            android:id="@+id/custom_canvas"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Just play with opacity and thickness.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But, with opacity we can only change the alpha value, and that appears to be light or dark, but they doesn't appear same as the pencil shades.. @FrankN.Stein

Comment: Yes, `opacity = alpha`. That's how you simulate if a pencil is more or less greasy (hard or soft)

Comment: The thing is it do not look much appealing like a pencil while in other android applications like Sketch, have a pencil like you are actually using a graphite pencil. @FrankN.Stein

Comment: I don't know Sketch but I guess they are using a custom brush.

Comment: So do you have any idea to make that custom brush?? @FrankN.Stein

Comment: A simple png with alpha (semi-transparent)?

Comment: Nope, need to draw something.

Comment: You can obviously draw the image onto your canvas.